# Suppose we have an orbit with period $11$. When do the two pebbles meet for transients $t = 0$, $11$, $22$, $23$?

Tags: functions

Background information : If the set $A$ is finite, then the trajectories of an endofunction
$f:A \mapsto A$ are particularly simple: they must ultimately wrap around. We get a lasso of the form transient $+$ period.

More background info - Here are more details. Think of two pebbles (or particles) moving down the orbit, the first at speed $1$ and the other at speed $2$. At time $0$
, both pebbles sit at the initial point of the orbit. They first move along the transient part (which may be empty) and ultimately both reach the periodic part, the loop at the end. But then the fast pebble must ultimately catch up with the slow one: it gets closer by one at each step. At the moment when the pebbles meet, we have found a point on the cycle. This concludes stage one. Now, in the second stage, we can run around the loop one more time stepping a counter, starting at the point we just found. Clearly this will give us the cycle length, which is none other than the period $p$ that we are after. Make sure you understand how one would do this. Now for the third stage. Since we now know the period $p$, we can race two new pebbles, this time both with speed $1$, but one with a head start of $p$, down the whole orbit, to determine the transient $t$: these two pebbles will meet exactly at the point where the transient part connects to the loop.

The answers are:

1. Transient $0$ - The pebbles meet after $11$ steps at the starting position
2. Transient $11$ - The pebbles meet after $11$ steps on position $0$ of the cycle
3. Transient $22$ - The pebbles meet after $22$ steps on position $0$ of the cycle
4. Transient $23$ - The pebbles meet after $33$ steps on position $10$ of the cycle

I really don't understand why the answer for transient $23$ is different from the other transients. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the final case you have a transient path of length 23, followed by a cycle of length 11.  By the time the slow pebble gets to the cycle, the fast pebble has moved 46 positions.  That is, the fast pebble has completed the 23 moves needed to get to the cycle, then completed 2 laps of the cycle, and and moved on one position: $$46=23+11+11+1$$
So after 23 steps, the fast pebble is one ahead of the slow pebble.  Of course on a cycle of length 11, being one ahead is the same as being 10 behind.  Thus it will take a further 10 steps for the fast pebble to catch up with the slow one.

Thus pebbles meet 10 steps after the first 23 steps which is 33 steps from the start.

Comment: why does the fast pebble complete 2 laps of the cycle?

Comment: The slow pebble needs 23 steps to get to the cycle, which means the fast pebble will have moved 46 positions: 46= 23 +11 +11 +1.  The two 11's here correspond to two laps.

Comment: Shouldn't the slow pebble only complete one lap if it's transient + period ?

Comment: I am saying that after 23 steps the slow pebble has just arrived at the cycle (not completed any laps), but the ${\it fast}$ pebble has completed 2 laps.

Comment: sorry I meant shouldn't the fast pebble only complete one lap if it's transient + period?

Comment: and the slow pebble should complete only transient

Comment: When the slow pebble has completed only the transient, the fast pebble has moved 46 positions - do you agree?  46 positions is the 23 needed to reach the cycle, plus 2 lots of 11 to do 2 laps, plus 1.